# How do I create a pause/wait function using Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, sleep, wait

I'm playing around with [Qt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28software%29), and I want to create a simple pause between two commands. However it won't seem to let me use `Sleep(int mili);`, and I can't find any obvious wait functions.

I am basically just making a console application to test some class code which will later be included in a proper Qt GUI, so for now I'm not bothered about breaking the whole event-driven model.

Comment: What exactly are you testing? What does adding a `wait()` or `sleep()` accomplish?

Comment: I am creating a class to drive a peristatic pump using RS232 serial commands. I have created a GUI in QT but in the mean time I am just testing the functions I have created from a main() function within the console.

Thus I want the class to be compiled by QT but at the same time I want to mypump.startpump(); sleep(1000); mypump.stoppump(); for instance. just to test it works.

Comment: Despite compiling with QT I am using CONFIG += console to run and output debugging strings to the console.

Comment: `QObject().thread()->usleep(1000*1000*seconds);` will sleep for `seconds` seconds :)

Comment: I wish you could up vote comments.  mlvijr's  answer worked perfect. You should make an answer.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149356/qt-make-a-function-to-pause-at-some-moment-for-some-time) mentions using `qSleep()` which is in the `QtTest` module. To avoid the overhead linking in the `QtTest` module, looking at the source for that function you could just make your own copy and call it. It uses defines to call either Windows `Sleep()` or Linux `nanosleep()`.

```
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
#include <windows.h> // for Sleep
#endif
void QTest::qSleep(int ms)
{
    QTEST_ASSERT(ms > 0);

#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
    Sleep(uint(ms));
#else
    struct timespec ts = { ms / 1000, (ms % 1000) * 1000 * 1000 };
    nanosleep(&ts, NULL);
#endif
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the including windows.h enables the use of Sleep(); This will do for now as I understand I will not be using this code in the final program because it breaks the event driven model but for now this enables me to test the program as is.

Comment: Where did you find the source?

Comment: It's now six years later and a few changed hands but you can find the open source version of Qt at https://www.qt.io/download-open-source. There are links there that will lead to the source code. I have no idea if the  code above still exists.

Answer (score 155):

I wrote a super simple delay function for an application I developed in Qt.

I would advise you to use this code rather than the sleep function as it won't let your GUI freeze.

Here is the code:

```
void delay()
{
    QTime dieTime= QTime::currentTime().addSecs(1);
    while (QTime::currentTime() < dieTime)
        QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 100);
}
```

To delay an event by n seconds - use `addSecs(n)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this beautiful function! Exactly what I was looking for as it does not suspend the main event loop.

Comment: This is one of those code nuggets that every now and then you come across and just think "Why didn't I think of that". Good job.

Comment: Am I only the one who experiences 100% CPU load when putting this in `while` loop in Qt 5.7?

Comment: Such delay functions using the clock time are the cause why many applications sometimes do not work as expected and nobody can easily reproduce the problem. Timeouts and delays should never use the clock time. The delay is wrong if date/time of machine running the application with this code is modified due to a date/time change between first `currentTime()` and any further `currentTime()` calls. Depending on date/time change the delay either expires too early or much too late (seconds, minutes, hours, days, months or even years too late). Usage of clock time for delays/timeouts is a no go.

Comment: The `processEvents()` function will return immediately if there are no pending events, which results in a busy loop (taking 100% of the CPU).  Hence, you should add logic in the loop to wait for the remainder of the 100ms loop time left.

Comment: This is extremely dangerous since 'processEvents' basically means 'anything can happen'. You may end up processing socket communication, it may cause Qt objects to get deleted - or the application to terminate. All that hidden behind a harmless looking `delay();` statement in your program.

Comment: **This is objectively awful.** Just call the existing static public `QThread.msleep()`, `QThread.usleep()`, or `QThread.sleep()` methods – as detailed by [what *should* have been the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29150102/2809027).

Comment: Do not use this. Other than the busy-waiting issue, QTime wraps around at midnight, so if this gets called shortly before then and misses its window, this code won't terminate. One way to get around this would be to use QElapsedTimer (since Qt4.7), although I'd personally use QEventLoop (see [dvntehn00bz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43003223/1796978)) instead.

Answer (score 108):

From Qt5 onwards we can also use

[**Static Public Members of QThread**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#static-public-members)

```
void    msleep(unsigned long msecs)
void    sleep(unsigned long secs)
void    usleep(unsigned long usecs)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's simple, easy to use, and does not eat up all your CPU cycles.

Comment: but still it will make GUI no responsive

Comment: @user889030 Of course it would. If you only want your own code to pause, you'll have to drain/process ui events yourself. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11487434/10126273

Answer (score 37):

Small +1 to [kshark27](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1526130/kshark27)'s answer to make it dynamic:

```
#include <QTime>

void delay( int millisecondsToWait )
{
    QTime dieTime = QTime::currentTime().addMSecs( millisecondsToWait );
    while( QTime::currentTime() < dieTime )
    {
        QCoreApplication::processEvents( QEventLoop::AllEvents, 100 );
    }
}
```

Comment: plus one, small note: I guess you `#include <QCoreApplication>` also ´#include <QTime>`

Comment: See comments above.  This can cause busy-wait 100% cpu usage under normal circumstances (empty event queue) and bigger issues of the system clock is adjusted when the loop is running.

Comment: #include <QtCore>

Answer (score 24):

I've had a lot of trouble over the years trying to get QApplication::processEvents to work, as is used in some of the top answers.  IIRC, if multiple locations end up calling it, it can end up causing some signals to not get processed (https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq27-responsive-guis.html).  My usual preferred option is to utilize a QEventLoop (https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq27-responsive-guis.html#waitinginalocaleventloop).

```
inline void delay(int millisecondsWait)
{
    QEventLoop loop;
    QTimer t;
    t.connect(&t, &QTimer::timeout, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
    t.start(millisecondsWait);
    loop.exec();
}
```

Comment: Great solution, even today. This should be the accepted answer. Works without hanging up the GUI and without hacky sleeps() or processEvents(). Thanks!

Comment: This SHOULD be the accepted answer.  It does not spike CPU, uses event system to expire timer, and no loops.

Answer (score 9):

We've been using the below class -

```
class SleepSimulator{
     QMutex localMutex;
     QWaitCondition sleepSimulator;
public:
    SleepSimulator::SleepSimulator()
    {
        localMutex.lock();
    }
    void sleep(unsigned long sleepMS)
    {
        sleepSimulator.wait(&localMutex, sleepMS);
    }
    void CancelSleep()
    {
        sleepSimulator.wakeAll();
    }
};
```

QWaitCondition is designed to coordinate mutex waiting between different threads.  But what makes this work is the wait method has a timeout on it.  When called this way, it functions exactly like a sleep function, but it uses Qt's event loop for the timing.  So, no other events or the UI are blocked like normal windows sleep function does.

As a bonus, we added the CancelSleep function to allows another part of the program to cancel the "sleep" function.

What we liked about this is that it lightweight, reusable and is completely self contained.

QMutex: http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qmutex.html

QWaitCondition: http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qwaitcondition.html

Comment: At least the [current implementation in qt5](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/8b91c6831546f884437122ce243b8a08c328a13c/src/corelib/thread/qwaitcondition_unix.cpp#L205) does not seem to communicate with event loop at all, so from the pov of "processing events" this is "interruptable sleep".

Answer (score 7):

To use the standard *sleep* function add the following in your .cpp file:

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

As of Qt version 4.8, the following *sleep* functions are available:

```
void QThread::msleep(unsigned long msecs)
void QThread::sleep(unsigned long secs)
void QThread::usleep(unsigned long usecs)
```

To use them, simply add the following in your .cpp file:

```
#include <QThread>
```

Reference: QThread (via Qt documentation):
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qthread.html

Otherwise, perform these steps...

Modify the project file as follows:

```
CONFIG += qtestlib
```

Note that in newer versions of Qt you will get the following error:

```
Project WARNING: CONFIG+=qtestlib is deprecated. Use QT+=testlib instead.
```

... so, instead modify the project file as follows:

```
QT += testlib
```

Then, in your .cpp file, be sure to add the following:

```
#include <QtTest>
```

And then use one of the sleep functions like so:

```
usleep(100);
```

Comment: these functions are protected !

Answer (score 6):

Since you're trying to "test some class code," I'd really recommend learning to use [QTestLib](http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qtestlib-manual.html). It provides a [QTest namespace](http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qtest.html) and a [QtTest module](http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qttest.html) that contain a number of useful functions and objects, including [QSignalSpy](http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qsignalspy.html) that you can use to verify that certain signals are emitted.

Since you will eventually be integrating with a full GUI, using QTestLib and testing without sleeping or waiting will give you a more accurate test -- one that better represents the true usage patterns. But, should you choose not to go that route, you could use [QTestLib::qSleep](http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qtest.html#qSleep) to do what you've requested.

Since you just need a pause between starting your pump and shutting it down, you could easily use a single shot timer:

```
class PumpTest: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Pump &pump;
public:
    PumpTest(Pump &pump):pump(pump) {};
public slots:
    void start() { pump.startpump(); }
    void stop() { pump.stoppump(); }
    void stopAndShutdown() {
        stop();
        QCoreApplication::exit(0);
    }
    void test() {
        start();
        QTimer::singleShot(1000, this, SLOT(stopAndShutdown));
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    Pump p;
    PumpTest t(p);
    t.test();
    return app.exec();
}
```

But `qSleep()` would definitely be easier if all you're interested in is verifying a couple of things on the command line.

**EDIT**: Based on the comment, here's the required usage patterns.

First, you need to edit your .pro file to include qtestlib:

```
CONFIG += qtestlib
```

Second, you need to include the necessary files:

- For the QTest namespace (which includes `qSleep`): `#include <QTest>`
- For all the items in the `QtTest` module: `#include <QtTest>`. This is functionally equivalent to adding an include for each item that exists within the namespace.

Comment: How do I include QTestlib? The #include <QTestlib.h> doesn't seem to be able to find it.

Answer (score 4):

[@kshark27](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1526130/kshark27)'s answer didn't work for me for some reason (because I use Qt 5.7?) so I ended up doing this:

```
while (someCondition) {

   // do something

   QApplication::processEvents();
   QThread::sleep(1); // 1 second

};
```

If this is done in the GUI thread, it obviously introduces a 1 second GUI lag before responding to user events. But if you can live with it, this solution is probably an easiest to implement and even Qt endorses it in their [Threading Basics](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html) article (see **When to Use Alternatives to Threads** section).

Answer (score 3):

we can use following method `QT_Delay`:

```
QTimer::singleShot(2000,this,SLOT(print_lcd()));
```

This will wait for 2 seconds before calling `print_lcd()`.

Comment: Every other answer on this thread will cause the Events to not be called.
This should be the Accepted Answer.

Answer (score 3):

This work fine with Qt5:

```
void wait( int ms ) {
   QElapsedTimer timer;
   timer.start();

   while ( timer.elapsed() < ms )
       QCoreApplication::processEvents();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to some answers here, but maybe a little more lightweight

```
void MyClass::sleepFor(qint64 milliseconds){
    qint64 timeToExitFunction = QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch()+milliseconds;
    while(timeToExitFunction>QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch()){
        QApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a cross-platform method of doing this, the general pattern is to derive from QThread and create a function (static, if you'd like) in your derived class that will call one of the sleep functions in QThread.

Comment: or even better -- see the last comment under the question (as of today), thanks for inspiring that :)