# How to give a delay in loop execution using Qt

Tags: qt, loops

In my application I want that when a loop is being executed, each time the control transfers to the loop, each execution must be delayed by a particular time. How can I do this?

Comment: see this question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752742/how-do-i-create-a-pause-wait-function-using-qt

Comment: that is for windows.can you tell me the solution for linux.I want to draw 5 rectangles,each after a delay of 500ms.please explain me for my example,if you can please.

Comment: That linked answer is not specific to windows. Also, pausing while in the paint routine will not allow you to see each rectangle get drawn with a delay in between. The sum total of the painting done there is displayed after that routine exits, not during. You need to return to the event loop before any part of the gui will update. One solution would be to use a timer and in the timeout() slot, increment some variable and then call update(). Have the paint routine look at this to see how many rectangles to draw. Each time the timer fires, more and more of your content will be painted.

Comment: can you provide a snapshot about how to do this by timer for paintevent.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

EDIT (removed wrong solution).
EDIT (to add this other option):

Another way to use it would be subclass QThread since it has protected *sleep methods.

```
QThread::usleep(unsigned long microseconds);
QThread::msleep(unsigned long milliseconds);
QThread::sleep(unsigned long second);
```

Here's the code to create your own *sleep method.

```
#include <QThread>    

class Sleeper : public QThread
{
public:
    static void usleep(unsigned long usecs){QThread::usleep(usecs);}
    static void msleep(unsigned long msecs){QThread::msleep(msecs);}
    static void sleep(unsigned long secs){QThread::sleep(secs);}
};
```

and you call it by doing this:

```
Sleeper::usleep(10);
Sleeper::msleep(10);
Sleeper::sleep(10);
```

This would give you a delay of 10 microseconds, 10 milliseconds or 10 seconds, accordingly. If the underlying operating system timers support the resolution.

Comment: This will pause the calling thread for a maximum time indicated by the milliseconds parameter or until the QThread completes its task. In other words, this pauses a thread until another thread completes. I don't think this is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you have only a thread and specify a number of milliseconds lower than ULONG_MAX this thread will wait for the number of specified milliseconds.

Comment: Ok, I think your alternate solution will work (haven't tried it) but the first option won't work if there is only one thread. If you call QThread::currentThread->wait(), Qt will report an error that a thread tried to wait on itself.

Comment: Edited my post, after Arnold Spence pointed out the first solution was not working. Thx Arnold.

Comment: this is not working as the code is giving an error as forward declaration of struct Qthread.

Comment: error appearing in the code:" error: incomplete type ‘QThread’ used in nested name specifier in the line 
    static void usleep(unsigned long usecs){QThread::usleep(usecs);}

Comment: but when i am using it within the painter event to draw 5 rect each after delay of 500ms,it hangs up for a times,and thn paints all the rects at same time.no delay.any suggestion??

Comment: You have to sleep between every time you draw a rectangle. It should work even in a paint event.

Comment: my code is: for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
       std::stringstream ss;
       ss << arr[i];
       ch=ss.str();
       QString qstr = QString::fromStdString(ch);
       painter.drawRect(x, y, 60, 60);
       painter.drawText(x+25,y+25,qstr);
       x=x+60;
Sleeper::msleep(500);
}

Comment: but this is not working properly as all the rectangles are drawn at same time and the application pauses before drawing them.

Comment: Does the application hangs for 500ms or 2.5 seconds?

Comment: and the speed of each operation in the application got very slow after applying the thread.it responds very late to the signals.why?

Comment: It is said in Qt doc that there is optimization in the paintEvent() method. Maybe it is a thread by itself and  cannot be but to sleep or adds up all the time it must sleep and then sleep for a longer time. If you try the Sleep in another method or simply to print a debug message does it work?

Comment: how to do this with paintevent?

Comment: The whole events system is handled by your QApplication and it processes events regularly. Since your paintEvent is treated as an event, it is processed by your QApplication.

Comment: You could try this but I have never tested it. qApp->thread()->msleep(500); This is not perfect because your main thread will be completey frozen for half a second. If it works for you it is good, but be careful with this.

Comment: Why the frig did the Qt makers feel the need to make that method protected?! It's static already, just make it public. Having to subclass QThread just to sleep() is beyond silly.

Answer (score 27):

As an update of [@Live's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3831460/1290438), for Qt ≥ 5.2 there is no more need to subclass `QThread`, as now the sleep functions are public:

> ### Static Public Members
>
> - `QThread *  currentThread()`
> - `Qt::HANDLE     currentThreadId()`
> - `int    idealThreadCount()`
> - `void   msleep(unsigned long msecs)`
> - `void   sleep(unsigned long secs)`
> - `void   usleep(unsigned long usecs)`
> - `void   yieldCurrentThread()`

cf http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qthread.html#static-public-members

Answer (score 9):

C++11 has some portable timer stuff. Check out [`sleep_for.`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)

Answer (score 1):

So this question is nearly 10 years old, but it popped up on one of my searches, and I think that there are better solutions when programming in Qt: Signals & slots, timers, and finite state machines. The delays that are required can be implemented without sleeping the application in a way that interrupts other functions, and without concurrent programming and without spinning the processor - the Qt application will sleep when there are no events to process.

A hack for this is to have a sequence of timers with their timeout() signal connected to the slot for the event, which then kicks off the second timer. This is nice because it is simple. It's not so nice because it quickly becomes difficult to troubleshoot and maintain if there are logical branches, which there generally will be outside of any toy example.

[QTimer](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtimer.html)

A better, more flexible option is the State Machine infrastructure within Qt. There you can configure an framework for an arbitrary sequence of events with multiple states and branches. An FSM is much easier to define, expand and maintain over time.

[Qt State Machine](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/statemachine-api.html)