# Qt: wait for some time in a function without hanging the UI

Tags: c++, qt

I came up with following code to wait in a function for a certain time without hanging the UI.

```
QEventLoop loop;
QTimer timer;
connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
timer.start(1000);
loop.exec();
```

I would like to know whether this can lead to any unexpected problems. Also, Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Why not to use `QTimer::singleShot()` function instead?

Comment: I want to access some local variables in the function after the timeout. If I use singleShot(), I would have to increase the scope of these variables.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831439/qthow-to-give-a-delay-in-loop-execution

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question if this code can lead to unexpected problems?  probably YES, will this crash often ? NO I do not think so.

A better way ? I believe yes, the first thing that I see is that you wait exactly 1 second for something that is happening somewhere outside this function, but what happens if 1 second is not enough and those variables are not ready yet?

Wouldn 't it be better simply to wait for your variables to be ready and have a function or a signal that alerts you when this data is available ?

Also you should never be stopped from writing a new function and more readable code because you need to access local variables, there are many ways to pass or to access local variables or maybe they should just not be local at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this you could run the message loop until a minimum amount of time has expired.

```
auto begin = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
while (std::chrono::system_clock::now() - begin > std::chrono::duration<double>(2))
{
    QCoreApplication::processEvents()
}
```

However I would advise rethinking what you are trying to do, sleeping for an arbitrary amount of time is almost never justified.