# How to interrupt io.read() in lua, which acts as "wait" function

Tags: qt, lua

I am programming a user interface with Lua and Qt, and there is a process to draw a rectangle on a picture for the following process. Currently I use io.read() to wait for the rectangle is set by the user, who then presses "CTRL + D" to continue the program. I wonder if I could interrupt io.read() by codes, so that once the rectangle is set by user, the program will run automatically.
To be more specific, here is a sample of what I will do.

```
function ui_select(x, y)
   if x1 == -1 then  -- First point of rectangle
      x1 = x
      y1 = y
   else     -- Second point of rectangle
      x2 = x
      y2 = y
      io.write(1)
   end
end
qt.connect(qt.QtLuaListener(ui.frame_2.canvas), 'sigMousePress(int, int, QByteArray, QByteArray, QByteArray)', ui_select)
x1 = -1
y1 = -1
x2 = 0
y2 = 0
ui.frame_2.can_label.text = 'Draw a rectangle around the object you want to track, finish with "<CTRL> + D"'
io.read()
-- Do something
```

I wonder if I could interrupt io.read() in ui_select function, so once users draw the rectangle, it will automatically start processing.

I can't just put the processing codes into ui_select function and delete io.read(), for this is the subprogram, and once there is no io.read() to wait for user's operation, it will just run from the beginning to the end without doing anything and goes back to the main program.

Comment: I don't understand the flow of your program, but in the Unix world there's something called FIFO: it's a "file" with which processes can communicate. Doing :read() on this file would block till there's input available (that is, till some other process writes something there. E.g., your drawing application could write "rectangle ready\n". But make sure to flush the output or it won't really be sent). (As for your "original" question: I know read(2) can be interrupted by a signal. You may want to check this venue.)

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more details about how to interrupt io.read(2)? It is by FIFO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "interrupt" `io.read()` function. You'll need to come up with a different mechanism to wait for the input. For example, you can have a loop where the process "sleeps" for 250ms or so and then does a check for the condition you are interested in. This way you can always "break" the loop and have various conditions that work for your case.

Comment: Is there a lower limit for the sleeping time of the loop? I have tried to use "while" loop but somehow the program is frozen there.

Comment: I'm sure qt has some API call that does sleep; see this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23169620/1442917) for examples.