# how to control the fps during video playing in qt using opencv?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I'm trying to control video playing in qt widget using opencv at certain fps(e.g. 30 fps).

There is a problem that I can't control the playing interval between two adjacent frames. Since the project is quite complex, I just show a few codes to describe the problem:

```
while(buffer.get(frame))
{
    currentTime = cvGetTickCount();

    waitTime = 1000/fps - (currentTime - lastTime)/msUnit;

    // I hope the thread waiting for 'waitTime' here.

    // I have tried to use QTimer to to control the interval, but it's not
    // accurate at the ms level. Therefore, I tried to use
    // 'QSemaphore.tryAcquire(1, waitTime )', since I have set the 
    // resource to be 0, so 'tryAcquire()' always fails and waited for 
    // expected time. Most of time it worked good, but sometime it didn't, 
    // awaken in later time. 

   lastTime= cvGetTickCount();

   emit NextFrame(frame);
}
```

In other words, I hope to control the time interval at millisecond level. Is there any way in qt or opencv, or other?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you simply use OpenCv's `waitKey()`.

Comment: Thanks, -@Optimus1072, The function `waitKey()` only works if there is at least one HighGUI window created and the window is active. However, opencv's gui supports a few functions while I needs more complex ones

Comment: why do you need to display frames with millisecond precision?

Comment: -@slawekwin Most videos are played at 25 fps or 30 fps, which means every frame needs to  last 1/25x1000=40ms or 1/30x1000=33.3ms. I hope to play video at different fps, that is, to control frame playing at least millisecond precision.

Comment: have you seen the `sleep(ms)` function?.

Comment: check this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/3831460/5717898

Comment: @Optimus1072 sleep(ms) looks good if the application is not complex. However, in multiple-thread programs, a thread will exchange data busily with others, where the sleeping thread may miss the waken clock and sleep time may be unexpected longer. Moreover, function `sleep` is not used for timer.

Comment: I have idea, making the thread's priority higher. But I'm not sure if it will solve my problem since the program currently works good,  no matter the thread's priority higher or not.