# Qt Stop application for a certain time

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I'm developing a Qt application. At some point in my program I have to pause the application and then start a function.

```
QTimer::singleShot(10000, this, SLOT(testFuntion()));
qDebug() << "after Singleshot";
```

And there lies my problem. The timer launches and I can see the output of my `testFuntion()`, but it doesn't pause the application. I can see immediately after my SingleShot the `qDebug` output and after 10 seconds the output of my `testFuntion()`.

Could you please help me solve this issue? Or is there any other command with which I can pause my application for a certain time and then run a function?

Comment: You should never "pause" the whole application, as then the user will most definitely be very frustrated when nothing happens for several seconds no matter what the user does. Instead just set a flag while the timer is in place, and don't do anything but react to the events from the GUI. You can even disable some, or all, GUI elements, but then I suggest you give a very clear notice to the user what's happening.

Comment: You can create your own Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752742/how-do-i-create-a-pause-wait-function-using-qt)

Comment: I thinked about you mention. 
In my MainWindow i start a Timer which launches a Function every second. But this Function produces the mistakes. 
So at the right place is just started a new QTimer: 
<code>      pauseCalculateTime.setSingleShot(true);
      pauseCalculateTime.singleShot(10000, this, SLOT(testFunction()));
      pauseCalculateTime.start();</code> 
But if i now say: 
<code> if (pauseCalculateTime.isActive() == false ) </code>
It just say every time "false" even if it (should) be "true"

Answer (score 2):

It is working the way it should. This line:

```
QTimer::singleShot(10000, this, SLOT(testFuntion()));
```

will launch the function when the timer will tick. However, the timer runs independently from the rest of the application, so after this line executes, the main app will continue to the `qDebug()` line.

If you really want to pause the application (which I really don't recommend, because the app becomes unresponsive), you can use `sleep()` and `usleep()` functions.

A better way would be displaying some kind of notification (maybe a progress-bar) for the user.

Comment: He could use [QEventLoop](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qeventloop.html) instead of sleep

Answer (score 0):

I found a really simple solution.

First at all if you user your timer Like this

```
QTimer *test = new QTimer();
test->isSingleshot(true);
connect(test, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(testFunction()));
test->start(10000)


test->isActive
```

is working.

But i just have to start another timer in my application only when this check gets true.

To clear things a little up. I check if a certain value is in an Textfile. If it is not there i will try it again in 5 minutes. If it is their i start an Timer wich count an amopunt of time. But this timer only works if he get the Value out of the file.
So i start the 1-Second timer if i got this value.
Before i started this timer in my MainWindows Construktor.And if this timer is not running everything works like it should.

User get a Message with the Description and then launches my MainWindow and nothings hangs.

Thanks for the Help
Greetings
Chris

Answer (score 0):

You can use [QEventLoop](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qeventloop.html). It's advantage over `sleep` is that it won't make your application unresponsive. It basically creates a nested event loop.

```
QEventLoop loop;
QTimer::singleShot(10000, &loop, SLOT(quit()));
loop.exec();
qDebug() << "after Singleshot";
```