# how to pause the program for some seconds?

Tags: qt, time

I want to pause my program for some seconds in a program that i'm writing by c++ Qt.in fact when the program arrive to one of my functions it stops for for example 5 seconds and then continue next lines.what should I do?

that function is a member function of a class and I want to o that work(pausing)for each instance of the class...

Comment: Is this in the main thread or a worker thread?

Comment: Could you provide details why you want to achieve this? I have a feeling...

Comment: each instance of a class...see the edited question please

Comment: I'm writing the solution of "dine of philosophers problem".to say them eat for some seconds I need this work.that one instance of my "philosopher class" eat(pause) for some seconds

Comment: Use the search function in StackOverflow you silly goose!

[Qt Wait Function][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752742/how-do-i-create-a-pause-wait-function-using-qt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Qt5 you can use the following trick:

```
QMutex mut;
mut.lock();
mut.tryLock(milliseconds);
mut.unlock(); // I am not sure if this is a necessity
```

With Qt4 you can use `QWaitCondition::wait()` on the mutex;

Keep in mind that if this is in your interface thread your gui will freeze until the interval ellapses.

Answer (score 5):

In case you really need to do that, you have several options
You can use [QThread's](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html#sleep) `sleep` methods by inheriting QThread and making them public (those are protected because it's generally a bad idea)

Or you can use [QEventLoop](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qeventloop.html#exec) `exec` together with [QTimer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtimer.html#singleShot). Connect timer's signal to QEventLoop's `quit()` slot. That will cause "non-blocking" wait, so your app will not stay frozen.

Or maybe you should instead split your code into two methods, make the second one a `slot` and call it with a timer when appropriate

EDIT: something like, in your eat method you use `QTimer::singleShot` to call `finishEating` slot after `X` seconds.
You might also want to read this: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/thread-basics.html