# Updating QPushButton propertices with "keyPressEvent" for multiple times with one press of a key()

Tags: c++, qt

I need to update my `QPushButton`'s background color when I have a function that reads a value from a 2D array and I assign that value to the color. It's working, but the only issue is that I only see it updating when I press the key and then the calculation happens and then when everything is done, it updates the latest result.

Here is the code for keyPressEvent:

```
void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *keyEvent)
{
    switch(keyEvent->key())
    {
    case Qt::Key_S:
        bool isEqual = true;
        //int x = 0;
        while (isEqual){
            for (int i = 0; i < 500000000; i++){
                ///////////////////////////////
            }
            funcs->RUN();
            isEqual = funcs->equal(funcs->worldGrid, funcs->nextGenGrid);
            if (!isEqual)
                funcs->arrayCpy2D(funcs->worldGrid, funcs->nextGenGrid);

            gridToUI();
            x++;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Here is the function that I run to update the Buttons:

```
void MainWindow::gridToUI(){
int b = 0;
for (int y = 1; y < 5; y++){
    for (int x = 1; x < 5; x++){
        if (*funcs->worldGrid[y][x] == 1){
            buttonArray[b]->setStyleSheet("background-color: black; border-style:                outset; border-radius: 10px; border-color: beige; font: bold 32px; padding: 6px;");
            cout << "val: " << *funcs->worldGrid[y][x] << endl;
        }else{
            buttonArray[b]->setStyleSheet("background-color: gray; border-style: outset; border-radius: 10px; border-color: beige; font: bold 32px; padding: 6px;");
        }
        b++;
    }
}
}
```

I'd appreciate your thoughts, I'm a newbie in C++.

Comment: What does `for (int i = 0; i < 500000000; i++){ ...` do? Do you want to implement a sleep function at this point?

Comment: Yeah I know I can use QT time, but just was trying to get it worked. Is there a good way for sleep function? But I don't think that's the reason that it doesn't update, any idea about what kind of Even should I use here?

Comment: Well, any good compiler kills nonsense code, so it might nerver get executed and thus all your iteraterions happen in milliseconds. Here you can find a sleep function for windows and linux: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752742/how-do-i-create-a-pause-wait-function-using-qt

Comment: But when I cout it hasn't been killed and it does cout a test, but buttons don't get any update unless the whole while is finished, any idea? (I'll use the sleep function)

Comment: Just found out the Answer: QCoreApplication::processEvents(); which manually makes the UI responsive.

Comment: Ideally, if you know that an operation is going to take long, you should execute it on a separate thread. [QtConcurrent::run](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtconcurrentrun.html) in combination with [QFutureWatcher](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfuturewatcher.html) makes this very easy.