# Is QObject or subclassing QThread better for executing and monitoring an external process?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qthread, qprocess, qobject

I have subclassed `QThread` and added to it some functionality such as starting a user-defined external process, monitoring its behaviour (has it started?, has it stopped, what is its exit code etc.) and reporting back to the main thread (that is updating the UI according to the state of the process) via slots and signal. I am however facing a problem:

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QProcess(0x2baa7a0), parent's thread is QThread(0x28150a0), current thread is WorkerForExtProcess(0x2b77680)
```

Here is my code:

```
class WorkerForExtProcess(QtCore.QThread):
  '''
  A worker thread used by each ThreadedWidget to do some specified amount of work
  '''
  EXT_PROC_STATUS_INACTIVE = 0
  EXT_PROC_STATUS_OK_RUNNING = 1
  EXT_PROC_STATUS_OK_FINISHED = 2
  EXT_PROC_STATUS_ERROR_FAIL_START = 3
  EXT_PROC_STATUS_ERROR_FAIL_QUIT = 4

  def __init__(self, ext_process_name):
    print('WorkerForExtProcess in thread %d' % QtCore.QThread.currentThreadId())
    QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
    self.ext_process_name = ext_process_name
    self.ext_process = QtCore.QProcess()
    self.signalFinishedExtProc = QtCore.SIGNAL('ext_proc_finished')
    self.signalProgressExtProc = QtCore.SIGNAL('ext_proc_progress')
#    self.emit(self.signalFinishedExtProc, self.EXT_PROC_STATUS_INACTIVE)

  def run(self):
    self.ext_process.start(self.ext_process_name)
    if self.ext_process.waitForStarted():
        print('External process "%s" was started successfully (PID: %d)' % (self.ext_process_name, self.ext_process.pid()))
        self.emit(self.signalFinishedExtProc, self.EXT_PROC_STATUS_OK_RUNNING)
    else: 
        print('Failed to start external process "%s"' % self.ext_process_name)
        self.emit(self.signalFinishedExtProc, self.EXT_PROC_STATUS_ERROR_FAIL_START)   
        return

    if self.ext_process.waitForFinished() and not self.ext_process.exitCode():
        self.emit(self.signalFinishedExtProc, self.EXT_PROC_STATUS_OK_FINISHED)
    else:
        print('Failed to quit external process "%s" properly' % self.ext_process_name)
        self.emit(self.signalFinishedExtProc, self.EXT_PROC_STATUS_ERROR_FAIL_QUIT)

    print('External process log:\n\tExit code: %dExit status: %d\n' % (self.ext_process.exitStatus(), self.ext_process.exitCode()))
```

The problem is that the instance of `QThread` is owned by the main thread as well as the `self.ext_process`. The `run()` itself is what is actually running in a separate thread.

Now if I create the `ext_process` variable and initialize it INSIDE the even loop that is contained in the `run()` method like this

```
def run(self):
    ext_process = QtCore.QProcess()
    ext_process.start(self.ext_process_name)
    ...
```

the issue is fixed since the thread affinity of the `QProcess` instance is INSIDE the additional thread that my subclass is representing.

However this has a major flaw - if I am to add some slots and signals that work with `ext_process` (for example send some POSIX signals) it cannot be anything else but a class attribute so that I can access it from everywhere. If I do that I return to where I was - `cannot create children for a parent that ...`.

If I switch to `QObject` will it fix this issue? As far as I know when using `QOBJECT.moveToThread(QTHREAD)` this basically changes the whole thread affinity of that `QObject` instance and from that moment on it is no longer residing in its previous thread but in a new one thus making my variable `ext_process` a class attribute will not cause such problem.

Comment: You don't need threads (explicitely) for spawning a process and monitor it. Just use QProcess and its signals in the main thread.

Comment: So `waitForStarted()` etc. won't block my UI if I do as you say?

Comment: It will block, but why use ``waitForStarted()`` and not react to the signal ``started()``

Comment: I've thought about using the signals but then I asked myself won't this still block the UI? After all these methods basically do emit `started()` etc. at the end but until then the block is still there or is it not?

Comment: They don't block the UI.

Comment: Okay, will give it a shot.

Comment: Okay, it doesn't block the UI however I have one state that requires calling `time.sleep()`: after getting the signal `finished()` I need to check whether the exit code and exit status are != 0 that is has the process exited properly. If that's not the case an icon in the UI displays an error notification, which stays there until the user fixes it. Otherwise I need to wait for a few seconds and then change the icon to inactive (from previously showing a successful exit). This blocking freezes my whole UI for let's say 5 seconds (depending on the interval set in `time.sleep()`).

Comment: you can [wait whilst executing the event loop](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11487434/2283946)

Comment: Why do you have to wait? In any case, you could use a `QTimer` for that.

Comment: Because I want to display the transition from "Process has finished successfully" to "Process currently inactive" in case the process was okay upon exit.While the process is starting I have one icon. While the process is running I have another one.When the process has exited I have another and also another for inactive (that is none of the above). After the state changes from running to finished I change the icons accordingly.In case of a normal exit I want to show for a brief moment the status of the process upon exit and then change to inactive.In case of error the icon stays in error state.

Comment: Will look at the code that @GPPK has linked.

Comment: Okay, if I combine @SebastianLange 's and GPPK 's comments I get the desired effect and without the need of a separate thread :))) Let the fight begin who of you two will write the answer so that I can mark it as accepted. I'm still interested though if for this situation QObject would actually resolve my problems (thread affinity and all that). If someone can give some info about it I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Do not use the delay option. Calling process Events is bad design. Use a ``QTimer`` and its signal ``timeout()``.

Comment: After I added new features I can no longer avoid the thread thing. Right now I'm implementing the widget, which has a QThread and a QObject (that starts the QProcess) in that QThread. Changes related to both the UI and the process are exchanged via signals and slots. I've decided to go with this design since I also have to implement a widget that actually actively controls a `detached` process and this will help me keep the implementation almost the same for both.