# Run a function with a delay in QT

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, time, delay

I want to create a function, let's say (qDebug() << "result" ;). I want to display the result 2 secs later, the delay must be in this function implemented. In other words :

```
void MainWindow::my_function()
{
     // Here I need something to make a delay of 2 secs
      qDebug() << "result";
}
```

Is there a method or something that allows to wait 2 secs and then executes the next line ?
I m looking for the easiest method on QT.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a pause/wait function using Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752742/how-do-i-create-a-pause-wait-function-using-qt)

Comment: What about `QTimer::singleShot()` or `QThread::sleep()` if you want to block the current thread?

Comment: i dont get the question... you want to create a function that is  getting called 2 seconds after what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my suggestion is to read first why sleep are a bad idea, specially when GUIS are involved..
anyways, you can since qt5

[**Functions of QThread**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#static-public-members)

```
void msleep(unsigned long msecs);
void sleep(unsigned long secs);
void usleep(unsigned long usecs);
```

using this in your code, you can do

```
void MainWindow::my_function(){
     // Here I need something to make a delay of 2 secs
     sleep(2);
     qDebug() << "result";
}
```

but as I said before, read 1st, because this will work, but will freeze the main window too, which is a not so nice idea when considering User Experience etc

Answer (score 4):

**Do NOT (mis)use sleep functions**

Sleep functions are a specialized tool which is incredibly easy to misuse, and Qt gives you a lot of better options. So do not use sleep functions unless you know what you are doing (if only to avoid starting a bad habit).

So, what are your options?

If you only want the 2 second delay (e.g. after the user presses a button) you could use a [`QTimer::singleShot()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#singleShot) which will call the function after the timer expires e.g.

```
QTimer::singleShot(2000, this, &MainWindow::printResultFunction)
```

Or you might use a local [`QEventLoop`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qeventloop.html) which you you will `exec` and then quit (again) using a timer e.g.

```
QEventLoop loop;
QTimer::singleShot(2000, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
loop.exec();
```

Or you might start a separate thread, which executes your function and in this function use (*gasp*) [`QThread::msleep()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html) As I said before sleep functions are a specialized tool - here you *know* what you are doing. You are not stalling your GUI thread and qt events. You are pausing the execution of a thread designed to do one thing: doing stuff, **waiting 2 seconds**, doing some more stuff and terminating.